# MalformedURLException in Java JDK 8 when trying to create an URL

Tags: java, url, jar

In have an exception now when I try to create an URL with nested jars indirections.

I have for example the following nested jar URL:

```
jar:jar:file:/D://samples/File.zip!/71812_file!/myFile.properties
```

It is a nested Jar URL with two indirections.

When I'm trying to perform this simple line:

```
URL url = new URL(spec);
```

I have the following exception:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Nested JAR URLs are not supported
```

It does not work anymore now (JDK8_271), but the same exact code worked in older JDK8 versions (for example 92 in my memory).

It seems that the "offending' code in the JDK which creates this exception (and was not present in the JDK code before) is in the sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler class (Source code [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/jar/Handler.java)):

```
   private String checkNestedProtocol(String spec) {
     if (spec.regionMatches(true, 0, "jar:", 0, 4)) {
       return "Nested JAR URLs are not supported";
     } else {
       return null;
     }
  }
```

What can I do to fix this now, and is it possible with newer JDK versions?

Comment: Why don't you simply extract the nested JAR? I mean, that kinda URL was not something I would have done anyway.

Comment: The file itself can be huge (approx. 40 MB). It's the reason why I avoided to perform the extraction.

Comment: Do you accept workarounds/alternatives? What do you need to do with your inner JAR?

Comment: I know that at one time, reading an entry in a .jar inside a .jar yielded terrible performance.  Perhaps when building your application, you should unzip File.zip into a separate directory and recursively add that directory to your main .jar?  (If you build with Ant, you can do this with a single [<zipfileset>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) line.)

Comment: In fact it is a huge zip file with two levels of zips inside by an external app I have to use, which is not a great idea, but I can't make them change their storage format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the real problem here is that the standard Java class loaders do not and never have supported nested JAR files.  There is a long standing feature request for this; see [JDK-4735639 : URLClassLoader does not work with jar: URLs](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4735639).

And the same applies to the opening a nested JAR with `URL.openConnection()`.

What has happened is that JDK 7(!) and later were changed (in June 2019) so that you now get a clear exception when you attempt to parser the URL.

If you cannot extract the nested JAR to a file, then the solution will be to find (or write) and register a 3rd-party URL protocol handler class for the `jar:` that understands nested JAR files.

One possibility is the JBoss `njar:` [protocol handler](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.4/common/org/jboss/net/protocol/njar/Handler.html).

---

> It does not work anymore now (JDK8_271), but the same exact code worked in older JDK8 versions (for example 92 in my memory).

What may have worked was parsing the URL.  But a comment in the `java.net.URL` class implies that `URL.openConnection` didn't work for nested `JAR` URLs.

```
if ("jar".equalsIgnoreCase(protocol)) {
    if (handler instanceof sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler) {
        // URL.openConnection() would throw a confusing exception
        // so generate a better exception here instead.
        String s = ((sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler) handler).checkNestedProtocol(file);
        if (s != null) {
            throw new MalformedURLException(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The custom URLConnection I used, with the protocol handler it works perfectly:

```
public class NestableURLConnection extends URLConnection {
  protected String urlPath;
  protected boolean firstEntry = false;
  public NestableURLConnection(URL url) {
     super(url);
     urlPath = url.toString();
  }

  public NestableURLConnection() {
     super(null);
  }

  public void setURL(URL url) {
     this.url = url;
     urlPath = url.toString();
  }

  public NestableURLConnection(URL url, boolean firstEntry) {
     this(url);
     this.firstEntry = firstEntry;
  }

  @Override
  public void connect() throws IOException {
     connected = true;
  }

  private String getNestedURL() throws IOException {
     int sep = urlPath.indexOf("!/");
     int start = urlPath.indexOf(':') + 1;

     for (int i = start, end = urlPath.indexOf("/") - 1; (i = urlPath.indexOf(":", i)) < end;) {
        int cursep = urlPath.indexOf("!/", sep + 2);
        if (cursep < 0) {
           break;
        }
        sep = cursep;
        ++i;
     }

     return urlPath.substring(start, sep);
  }

  @Override
  public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
     int start = urlPath.indexOf(':') + 1;
     if (start > urlPath.length() || urlPath.charAt(start) == '/') {
        return url.openStream();
     }

     if (FileUtilities.useFileOrHTTPProtocol(urlPath)) {
        return url.openStream();
     }

     int sep = urlPath.indexOf("!/");
     if (sep < 0) {
        throw new MalformedURLException("Missing separator " + urlPath);
     }

     String nestedURL = getNestedURL();

     sep = urlPath.indexOf(nestedURL) + nestedURL.length();
     int nextSep = urlPath.indexOf("!/", sep + 2);

     // Use the default Java openStream() for a file scheme.
     InputStream inputStream;
     ZipEntry inputZipEntry;
     boolean isKnownProtocol = FileUtilities.useFileOrHTTPProtocol(nestedURL);
     if (!isKnownProtocol || (firstEntry)) {
        if (firstEntry) {
           nestedURL = urlPath;
        } else {
           if (!nestedURL.contains("!/")) {
              nestedURL = "file:" + nestedURL.substring(4);
           }
        }
        inputStream = createInputStream(nestedURL);
     } else {
        String entry = nextSep < 0 ? urlPath.substring(sep + 2) : urlPath.substring(sep + 2, nextSep);

        sep = nextSep;
        nextSep = urlPath.indexOf("!/", sep + 2);

        // Go directly to the right entry in the zip file
        final ZipFile zipFile = new  ZipFile(FileUtilities.replaceEscapedSequences(nestedURL.substring(5)));
        inputZipEntry = zipFile.getEntry(entry);
        InputStream zipEntryInputStream = inputZipEntry == null ? null :   zipFile.getInputStream(inputZipEntry);
        if (zipEntryInputStream == null) {
           zipFile.close();
           // return null instead of throwing an Exception if the URL does not exist
           return null;
        }
        inputStream = new FilterInputStream(zipEntryInputStream) {
           @Override
           public void close() throws IOException {
              super.close();
             zipFile.close();
           }
        };
     }

     // Loop over the archive paths.
     LOOP:
     while (sep > 0) {
        // The entry name to be matched.
        String entry = nextSep < 0 ? urlPath.substring(sep + 2) : urlPath.substring(sep + 2, nextSep);

        // Wrap the input stream as a zip stream to scan it's contents for a match.
        // Don't use try-with-resources here because we only want to close it if there is an internal IOException
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
        while (zipInputStream.available() >= 0) {
           ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
           if (zipEntry == null) {
              break;
           } else if (firstEntry) {
              inputZipEntry = zipEntry;
              inputStream = zipInputStream;
              sep = -1;
              continue LOOP;
           } else if (entry.equals(zipEntry.getName())) {
              inputZipEntry = zipEntry;
              inputStream = zipInputStream;

              // Skip to the next archive path and continue the loop.
              sep = nextSep;
              nextSep = urlPath.indexOf("!/", sep + 2);
              continue LOOP;
           }
        }
        throw new IOException("Archive entry not found " + urlPath);
     }

     return inputStream;
  }

  private InputStream createInputStream(String nestedURL) throws IOException {
     return new URL(nestedURL).openStream();
  }

  @Override
  public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
     return null;
  }
```

I have added it in my library here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mdiutilities/

Answer (score -1):

hmm now I understand! In fact I already created my own URLConnection, because I did not use the url.openConnection code, exactly for the reason you explain (but before I did not have an exception just when trying to create the URL, hence my current problem). I had the following code:

```
NestableURLConnection conn = new NestableURLConnection(url);
```

with NestableURLConnection being a custom URLCustom connection I created. I will try your solution, which seems to be very appropriate!